# Compute the Strahler number of each node

Tags: xslt, xquery

The [Strahler number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strahler_number) of a node
in a tree is a generalization of the notion of height of a node.

The goal is to define a transformation which adds a number attribute, say `strahler`, to each node of the XML document.

Inductively the Strahler number of a node `n`, denoted `Stn(n)`, is defined as follows:

- if `n` is a leaf, then `Stn(n)=0`
- else (`n` is not a leaf) sort its children (`n1`,...,`nd`) by descending Strahler value: `Stn(n1)` ≥  `Stn(n2)` ≥
  ... ≥
  `Stn(nd)`. 
  If `Stn(n1) = Stn(n2)` then `Stn(n)=n1+1`; otherwise `Stn(n)=Stn(n1)`.

E.g. for node `n` with children `n1` `n2` `n3` with Stn `1` `2` `3` respectively, the Stn of `n` is `3` (since the maximum occurs only once). For node `n` with children `n1` `n2` `n3` with Stn `1` `2` `2`, respectively, the Stn of `n` is again `3` (since the maximum occurs more than once).

**Sample input**:

```
<root field="4">
<a>
    <aa x="1"/>
    <ab>
        <aba number="36" usefulness="useful">
            <abaa>text1</abaa>
            <abab>
                <ababa>text2</ababa>
            </abab>
        </aba>
        <abb number="37" usefulness="useful">
            <abba>text3</abba>
            <abbb>
                <abbba>text4</abbba>
                <abbbb>text5</abbbb>
            </abbb>
        </abb>
    </ab>
</a>
</root>
```

**Output**:

```
<root strahler="2" field="4">
<a strahler="2">
    <aa strahler="0" x="1"/>
    <ab strahler="2">
        <aba strahler="1" number="36" usefulness="useful">
            <abaa strahler="0">text1</abaa>
            <abab strahler="0">
                <ababa strahler="0">text2</ababa>
            </abab>
        </aba>
        <abb strahler="1" number="37" usefulness="useful">
            <abba strahler="0">text3</abba>
            <abbb strahler="1">
                <abbba strahler="0">text4</abbba>
                <abbbb strahler="0">text5</abbbb>
            </abbb>
        </abb>
    </ab>
</a>
</root>
```

Comment: I would like to humbly suggest reformatting this question such that you can expect a proper response.  As far as I can tell, it's unclear what you are inquiring about.

Comment: You're more likely to get response if you include smallest set of sample XML to illustrate your problem,plus required output, current XSLT code, current output and *then* your thoughts about the problem. Good luck.

Comment: when you say: "Stn of n equals Stn of n1+1 to the Stn" what is the third Stn? I read this as stn(n) = stn(n+1)^stn (where ^ means "to the power of"), but stn is not a number, it is a function. In fact, I can't find any interpretation of your rules that gives any node an Stn other than zero.

Comment: I updated the question with sample input/output and broken code. I also fixed a few typos.

Comment: @bardamu, Good question, +1. See my answer for a shorter XSLT 2.0 solution.

Comment: Deleted my broken code just to leave the question and input / output samples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This shorter and  efficient   XSLT 2.0 transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
 xmlns:f="my:f">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[true()]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:attribute name="strahler" select="f:strahler(.)"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:function name="f:strahler" as="xs:integer" saxon:memo-function="yes">
    <xsl:param name="pElem" as="element()"/>

    <xsl:sequence select=
     "if(not($pElem/*))
        then 1
        else 
           if(not($pElem/*[2]))
             then f:strahler($pElem/*[1])
             else for $maxVal in max($pElem/*/f:strahler(.)),
                      $twoWithMax in 
                           (($pElem/*[f:strahler(.) eq $maxVal])[2]/1, 0)[1]
                    return $maxVal+$twoWithMax
     "/>
  </xsl:function>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<root field="4">
    <a>
        <aa x="1"/>
        <ab>
            <aba number="36" usefulness="useful">
                <abaa>text1</abaa>
                <abab>
                    <ababa>text2</ababa>
                </abab>
            </aba>
            <abb number="37" usefulness="useful">
                <abba>text3</abba>
                <abbb>
                    <abbba>text4</abbba>
                    <abbbb>text5</abbbb>
                </abbb>
            </abb>
        </ab>
    </a>
</root>
```

**produces the correct result** (note that the official definition of a ***[Strahler number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strahler_number#Definition)*** gives `1` to a leaf node -- not 0):

```
<root field="4" strahler="3">
      <a strahler="3">
            <aa x="1" strahler="1"/>
            <ab strahler="3">
                  <aba number="36" usefulness="useful" strahler="2">
                        <abaa strahler="1">text1</abaa>
                        <abab strahler="1">
                              <ababa strahler="1">text2</ababa>
                        </abab>
                  </aba>
                  <abb number="37" usefulness="useful" strahler="2">
                        <abba strahler="1">text3</abba>
                        <abbb strahler="2">
                              <abbba strahler="1">text4</abbba>
                              <abbbb strahler="1">text5</abbbb>
                        </abbb>
                  </abb>
            </ab>
      </a>
</root>
```

---

**Even more compact and efficient solution with XSLT 3.0 / XPath 3.0**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:f="my:f">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[true()]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="strahler" select="f:strahler(.)"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:function name="f:strahler" as="xs:integer" cache="full">
        <xsl:param name="pElem" as="element()"/>

        <xsl:sequence select=
         "let $children := $pElem/*
           return
              if(not($children))
                then 1
                else 
                  if(not($children[2]))
                    then f:strahler($children[1])
                    else 
                      let $childrenStrahler := $children/f:strahler(.),
                          $maxVal := max($childrenStrahler),
                          $twoWithMax := ($childrenStrahler[. eq $maxVal][2]!1, 0)[1]
                        return $maxVal +$twoWithMax 
            "/>
    </xsl:function>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

**Efficiency**:

> XSLT is not likely the optimal tool for this ...

If someone tells you this, don't believe them.

**Both presented solutions are efficient, by using memoization**.

In fact, `f:stahler($aNode)` is calculated only once for each different element.

Do note the use of:

1. `saxon:memo-function="yes"`
2. `cache="full"`

The first is one of [**Saxon's extension attributes**](http://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation9.4/extensions/attributes/). As per the documentation of [saxon:memo-function](http://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation9.4/extensions/attributes/memo-function.html):

> Specifying "yes" indicates that Saxon should remember the results of
>   calling the function in a cache, and if the function is called again
>   with the same arguments, the result is retrieved from the cache rather
>   than being recalculated.

The second is a **[standard feature of XSLT 3.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#memoization)**:

> The value cache="full" encourages the processor to retain memory of
>   all previous calls of this function during the same transformation and
>   to reuse results from this memory whenever possible. The value
>   cache="partial" encourages the processor to retain such memory but to
>   discard results if necessary to keep the amount of memory used within
>   bounds. The default value cache="no" encourages the processor not to
>   retain memory of previous calls.

Answer (score 1):

XSLT is fine for the job, and Dimitre's solution is perfect (+1).

Here is what an alternative implementation in [XQuery 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery/) might look like:

```
declare function local:strahler($nodes as node()*) as node()*
{
  for $node in $nodes
  return
    typeswitch ($node)
    case document-node() return
      document {local:strahler($node/node())}
    case element() return
      element {node-name($node)}
      {
        let $children := local:strahler($node/node())
        let $max := (max($children/@strahler), 1)[1]
        return
        (
          $node/@*,
          attribute strahler {$max + (($children/@strahler[. = $max])[2]/1, 0)[1]},
          $children
        )
      }
    default return
      $node
};

local:strahler(.)
```

When put in file `strahler.xq`, with the input in `sample.xml`, it can be run from the command line, using [Saxon](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/), with this command:

```
java net.sf.saxon.Query strahler.xq -s:sample.xml
```

Like the XSLT variant, it rewrites the document while adding the new attributes bottom-up. The rewriting here is more visible than with XSLT, which however in this case is quite adequate.

Comment: You solution also looks great, +1. Running it under Oxygen with Saxon produces this error: "Severity: error
Description: XTTE0600: An empty sequence is not allowed as the value of parameter $current-configuration ".  Also, is it legal to have expr/1 ? Probably only in XQuery?

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev, the error message is a case for Oxygen support, I guess. At least I can't see any relation to the XQuery code shown here. Concerning `expr/1`, IMHO it is perfectly legal. See the 5th example of [FilterExpr](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery/#doc-xquery-FilterExpr), which shows a filter expression as a step in a path expression. From XQuery 3.0, there also is the [simple map operator](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-30/#id-map-operator) for cases like this. Its specification contains a comparison with the path operator.

Comment: I actually verified that expr/1 doesn't raise an error only in XQuery. It produces an error in XPath.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev, this should work in XPath 2.0, too. But the left hand side of the path operator must a node sequence. This applies to XQuery as well. For non-nodes, there is the XPath 3.0 simple map operator.

Comment: No, in XPath 2.0 / 3.0 this causes an error. The rules do allow a function call as the last location step, but not any atomic value.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev, could you please point me to the rule that disallows it? I failed to find that, also two implementations that I checked are fine with it (Saxon and Frameless).

Comment: Gunter, You are right! This is supported and called "simple mapping expression" in Xpath 2.0. But this is the first time I see an example where the last location step isn't a function call. Thanks, I edited my solutions to use this more compact expressions and I believe this is an improvement.

Comment: And `expr/1`  is allowed only if *expr* is a sequence of nodes. If *expr* is not a sequence of nodes, then in XPath 3.0 one may use the simple mapping operator: `expr ! 1`, but in XPath 2.0 one has to use a *for-expression*

Answer (score 0):

XSLT is not likely the optimal tool for this, primarily because it cannot really traverse the tree from bottom up. It *is* possible to add the Strahler numbers to the tree one level at a time, starting at the deepest level - but the entire tree must be reprocessed each time, leading to a very inefficient algorithm.

Still, if no other way is available, you could try something like this:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="max-depth" select="max(//*/count(ancestor::node()))"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:call-template name="strahler">
        <xsl:with-param name="node-set" select="*"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="current-level" select="$max-depth"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="strahler">
    <xsl:param name="node-set" select="*"/>
    <xsl:param name="current-level"/>

    <xsl:variable name="next-set">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$node-set" mode="strahler">
            <xsl:with-param name="current-level" select="$current-level"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$current-level > 1">
            <!-- recursive call -->
            <xsl:call-template name="strahler">
                <xsl:with-param name="node-set" select="$next-set"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="current-level" select="$current-level - 1"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$next-set"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="strahler">
    <xsl:param name="current-level"/>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:if test="count(ancestor::node()) = $current-level">
            <xsl:attribute name="strahler">
                <xsl:variable name="max-strahler" select="max(*/@strahler)" />
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="not(*)">
                        <xsl:value-of select="1"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="count(*[@strahler=$max-strahler]) > 1">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$max-strahler + 1"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$max-strahler"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="strahler">
            <xsl:with-param name="current-level" select="$current-level"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input example, the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root strahler="3" field="4">
   <a strahler="3">
      <aa strahler="1" x="1"/>
      <ab strahler="3">
        <aba strahler="2" number="36" usefulness="useful">
            <abaa strahler="1">text1</abaa>
            <abab strahler="1">
                <ababa strahler="1">text2</ababa>
            </abab>
        </aba>
        <abb strahler="2" number="37" usefulness="useful">
            <abba strahler="1">text3</abba>
            <abbb strahler="2">
                <abbba strahler="1">text4</abbba>
                <abbbb strahler="1">text5</abbbb>
            </abbb>
        </abb>
      </ab>
   </a>
</root>
```

This is different from the result you posted, but I believe it is correct according to the rules in the Wikipedia article you linked to.

Note that "height" is not useful here.

Comment: Your solution computes the *correct* values and the "off by 1" in comparison to my sample output is not relevant. You claim XSLT is not optimal for this computation. What would be?

Comment: "*You claim XSLT is not optimal for this computation. What would be?*" I am afraid I haven't got a clue. During my Google search I came across this http://blog.phytools.org/2013/04/computing-strahler-numbers-for-nodes-on.html but I don't know anything about it.